# lambda expression join list<object> with list<string>

Tags: c#

I have `List<object>` and `List<string>` with records. I want inner join both list.

Following is my list with records.

```
var listContributionDetailsToBeUpdated = new List<ContributionDetailModel> 
{
    new ContributionDetailModel { EmployeeNumber="1", EmployeeFirstName="david", EmployeeLastName="k", NHIPNumber="nhi-100" },
    new ContributionDetailModel { EmployeeNumber="2", EmployeeFirstName="xavior", EmployeeLastName="f",NHIPNumber="nhi-101"},
    new ContributionDetailModel { EmployeeNumber="3", EmployeeFirstName="george", EmployeeLastName="s", NHIPNumber="nhi-102" },
    new ContributionDetailModel { EmployeeNumber="4", EmployeeFirstName="pandit", EmployeeLastName="h",NHIPNumber="nhi-103"},
    new ContributionDetailModel { EmployeeNumber="5", EmployeeFirstName="zania", EmployeeLastName="d", NHIPNumber="nhi-104" }
};

var updatedRecored = new List<string> { "nhi-100", "nhi-101", "nhi-102" };
```

Can any one help me to inner join both list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty straight-forward. Just select `NHIPNumber` from contribution details as key for joining:

```
var result = from c in listContributionDetailsToBeUpdated
             join r in updatedRecored on c.NHIPNumber equals r
             select c;
```

Method syntax:

```
var result = listContributionDetailsToBeUpdated
     .Join(updatedRecored, c => c.NHIPNumber, r => r, (c, r) => c);
```

You can also use filtering instead of joining, but it's not optimal way, because join is a set operation and it uses internal lookup for joined collection. With simple filtering you will have complexity O(N*M) instead of O(N+M)

```
var result = listContributionDetailsToBeUpdated
     .Where(c => updatedRecored.Contains(c.NHIPNumber));
```

Comment: Can any one help me to get all records Except "updatedRecored".Updated records is var updatedRecored = new List<string> { "nhi-100", "nhi-101", "nhi-102" };

Comment: @Vijeeshkumarvofox that should be another question :) simplest solution `.Where(c => !updatedRecored.Contains(c.NHIPNumber))`. For better performance you can use group join (i.e. `join ... into g`) and filter by `where !g.Any()` or use hashset instead of list for npi numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The following may also work:

```
var result = listContributionDetailsToBeUpdated.Where(x => updatedRecored.Contains(x.NHIPNumber));
```